How do I make a crafted diamond block placeable in Adventure mode?
I'm building a escape map on Xbox edition to be played on Adventure mode as I don't trust my family. Anyways, I want them to be able to craft a diamond block and then place it in the last spot to make the beacon work. Throughout the map there's 9 diamonds for them to grab. At the end is the chest. How can I make it so they use those 9 diamonds to craft into a diamond block and place on another diamond block?

Welcome to Arqade! Please see our guide on asking Minecraft commands questions, especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far.” Then, [edit] your post and add the requested information.

OK, so:
Step 1: Repeating command block feeding into a Impulse command block set to conditional
Step 2: Repeating Command Block Code: /clear @p [hasitem={diamond_block}] diamond_block
Step 3: Impulse Command Block Code: /give @p minecraft:diamond_block{CanPlaceOn["minecraft:blue_wool"]}
Or:
Use /execute which I currently don't have time to explain.

You may do this command for an adventure map:
/give @s minecraft:oak_button{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:diamond_block"]}
This gives you an oak button that is only placeable on a block of diamond.

This doesn't seem to actually answers the question

Well, if you want it to be a diamond block, you simply replace oak button with diamond block. Then, add what you want it to be placeable on

/give @s minecraft:diamond_block{CanPlaceOn:["sandstone"]}

@AstroFrikken The difficulty OP is encountering is that the player is required to craft the block before they can place it, as part of the adventure map challenge. This means the item cannot simply be given to the player using a command. The problem is, how to add the NBT data (i.e. CanPlaceOn) to an existing item (the diamond block the player has just crafted) upon their taking it out of the crafting table grid.

Of course, it would also work to replace the block the player has just crafted (which doesn't have the required CanPlaceOn attribute) with one given via command that does have it, but there's still the issue of how to detect the player having crafted the item and then replace it in the inventory.
